# Book ID: Kids Sci-Fi novel moon people plan to destroy the earth

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, moon

Read 1978-1982
People of the moon believe that the Earth orbits the moon, and plan to destroy the earth as it is some sort of nuisance to them. Discovering that the moon orbits the Earth, they cancel their plans.

In this book (or possibly a sequel) they later make a mission to visit the "Untied Steaks of America".