# Would like to identify book about aliens from moon trying to destroy earth

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

There was a story I read long ago, probably early 80s.  I think it may have had several points of view, from humans and from the moon beings.  The moon beings had no noses, and "breathed" vacuum.  There was actually a point where a moon being put on a helmet to breathe in fresh vacuum instead of air.  The moon beings wanted to destroy the earth by starting a bunch of volcanoes (I think).  It was young adult I think, I was probably around 8th or 9th grade.  I remember the moon beings talking about the "Untied Snakes of Ameligo" (or maybe Stakes).  This question is similar, probably same, but nobody answered: [Book ID: Kids Sci-Fi novel moon people plan to destroy the earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126106/book-id-kids-sci-fi-novel-moon-people-plan-to-destroy-the-earth)

Thanks

Comment: If they had no noses, how did they smell?

Comment: Right, it was a kids novel.  Still kind of a fun read, even with the scientific inaccuracies.

Comment: @Valorum: Terrible, no doubt.

Comment: @Valorum This was it: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/132564/childrens-sf-book-about-moon-folk-going-to-live-on-another-planet?rq=1, which you edited.  Finally found it after years.  I wonder if I should post it as an answer, or someone else should, so that I can accept it.

Comment: @lsd - No need. Since it's a dupe, I can close it